# Чтение данных из файла

Tags: java, android, файлы, filestream

Есть файл, в котором есть следующие строки:

```
1-А: 29
1-Б: 30
1-Я: 0
```

Это пример данных классов, в которых сказано количество учеников (в 1-А 29 учеников и т.д.)

За числа отвечает переменная которая записывает в файл данные:

```java
file.write("1-A: "+first_A);
file.write("1-Б: "+first_B);
file.write("1-Я: "+first_YA);
```

Данные переменные хранятся в отдельном классе Sharedpraferences.

Как считать данные из файла для каждой переменной?

Например, во всех переменных значение `0`, а в файле другие числа. Как можно считать из файла строку и записать количество учеников в свою же переменную?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код, с которым у вас проблема. Сложно понять без кода, что с ним не так. Из вопроса не совсем понятно, где хранятся данные, в обычном файле или вы используете [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences). Также не совсем ясно, что такое `file`, как вы объявляете эту переменную.

Comment: Кроме этого, у вас в вопросе какая-то путаница. Вы пишете в коде `"1-A"`, а в файле почему-то у вас `"1-А"`. Сравните строки: в первом случае буква английская, а во-втором случае — русская. Будьте внимательны.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос, что такое `first_A`, `first_B` и `first_YA`? Как они определяются у вас в коде? Отредактировать вопрос можно, нажав на кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1477747/edit) под вопросом.

Answer (score 1):

В Java много разных способов читать из файла. Один из способов, который подходит для вашей задачи — использовать класс [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) из пакета `java.util`.

Читаем все данные из файла с помощью `Scanner` и записываем их в `Map`:

```java
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String key = scanner.next();
        int value = scanner.nextInt();
        map.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

Вытаскиваем данные из `Map`:

```java
int second_A = map.get("1-A:");
int second_B = map.get("1-Б:");
int second_YA = map.get("1-Я:");
```

Будьте внимательны с ключами, не перепутайте `"1-A"` и `"1-А"` — это разные строки.

Comment: используя ваш код, то при первом нажатии всё хорошо, а при втором ошибка `InputMismapException ` из-за строчки `int value = scanner.nextInt`
Добавил try catch на эту строчку и жалуеться на `int second_A = map.get("1-A");` Но я присваиваю значение к существуюещей переменной, но в вашем коде вызодит мы создём новую переменную

Comment: Не очень понятно, куда вы нажимаете, в вашем вопросе об этом не было сказано. Вы можете отредактировать ваш вопрос, добавив туда детали. Или лучше задайте [новый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Присваивать значение к существующей переменной или заводить новую — в рамках данного вопроса не вижу особой разницы.